# Website Themes in PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics, themes, gimp, psd

There are graphic design websites that release themes and website graphics as PSD files.  Some examples:

A theme: http://www.wordpressthemeshock.com/psd-themes/

Graphic elements: http://www.wordpressthemeshock.com/ribbons-set-free-psd/

I've looked at the PSD files in GIMP, and each element is nicely layered, with sublayers for the text, etc.  The layers are also the size of the elements themselves.  Is there an easy way to isolate out a layer with its sublayers, and create a new PSD file with the single element?

I can get access to a machine with Photoshop if need be, but if this is possible in GIMP, or another free tool, that'd would be great.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/471446/143655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GIMP, use the Layers window to select the layer you want to isolate.  This will highlight the layer with a dashed-line box.

In the main image window, under the Edit menu, select Copy.  Then from the File menu, select Create, then Create from Clipboard.

This creates a new image within the boundaries of the selected layer.  No cropping required (as long as the layer is the size of the element, and not the full image.)  The one thing about this method is that it flattens the image, merging any sublayers together.  Just need to do the major edits within the original image before copying the layers.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an idea to simply duplicate the master file, then delete the layers you don't want, leaving the ones with the single element in and then save that file? I would see that possible even in GIMP.

Comment: Excellent suggestion for sure.  I was able to remove the layers I was not looking for in GIMP.  Getting closer to my goal.  Now, I just need to crop to the layer to remove all the empty space around the layer, and end up with just to the element.  I could try to do it manually, but if that could be done using an option in the drop list, something like "Crop to Layer", that would be perfect.