# Take a psd and export all the layers into separate image files without using Photoshop

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, gimp, layers, psd

This is my first question here and I'm not sure if this is the appropriate site for my question, but here it goes. If this is not the correct site, please direct me to the correct one.

I have a psd file. I simply want to extract the layers from it into separate image files. I do not have Photoshop and I've already used up the free Photoshop trial.

I am running Mountain Lion on a MacBook Pro. I have installed Gimp, but I can't figure out how to do what I want. I have searched using Google, but have been completely unable to find a tutorial showing me how to do this.

I would really appreciate instructions or a link to an appropriate tutorial. I have seen some answers here, but they simply say use Gimp, which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to install any plugin, do this using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) (open source tool):

1. Select the layer and copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or `Edit > Copy`
2. Then `Select > File > Create > From Clipboard`, this creates a new
   document from the copied layer, or you can just make the layer you
   want the only thing visible.
3. Then `select > File > Save As...` then go down to "Select File Type (By Extension)"
4. In the box where it says "All images select that box and go down to "PNG image (*.png)"

Comment: Is there a way to select multiple layers at the same time?

Comment: there is no file > create > from clipboard

Comment: simply a File > Create will take the clipboard image dimensions by default. After that just paste.

Comment: Instead of Save As you can use Export As option.

Answer (score 33):

There is a tool from Telegraphics called [PSDParse](http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/psdparse) that should do the trick.

```
psd2png.exe -w Filename.psd

usage: psd2png.exe [options] psdfile...
-h, --help show this help
-v, --verbose print more information
-q, --quiet work silently
-w, --writepng write PNG files of each raster layer (and merged composite)
-d, --pngdir dir put PNGs in directory (implies --writepng)
-m, --makedirs create subdirectory for PNG if layer name contains \'s
-l, --list write an 'asset list' of layer sizes and positions
-s, --split write each composite channel to individual (grey scale) PNG
```

Here's a link to the version I used, or you can go to the website for the latest version for your operating system.

http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/files/psdparse-1.7b1-win.zip

Comment: smal, simple, great tool to extract psd layers!

Comment: Do you know any alternative for Linux?

Answer (score 7):

There's a plugin for that: [Export Layers as PNG](http://registry.gimp.org/node/18440).

It adds an entry to the File menu, Export layers -> as png.

Comment: That looks like what I want, but can you tell me how to install it?

Comment: Look here http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-scripting.html#gimp-plugins-install

Comment: "Save as" to the file `export_layers-0.6.py.txt` and save it in the gimp sub folder `lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins` removing the .txt extension. Perhaps you need to add execution rights to the file after downloading it.

Answer (score 7):

You can export layers to assets like PNG, JPG or SVG from a new service called "Extract" that is in Adobe's Creative Cloud. You don't need Photoshop.

You can try it here: http://www.adobe.com/go/extract_tweet1

You'll need a Creative Cloud login, but, even free accounts can use the service.

1. Login to creative.adobe.com/files
2. Upload a PSD
3. Go to the Extract tab.
4. Select any layer and extract an asset.

You'll need to extract each asset individually, at the moment. No way to do it all at once.

Comment: Just to say that now, Extract is not free, cost 40$/month... I'm sad

Comment: @Metal3d I think (and hope) that it is still free. I have [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) and Extract is built into the editor. I just tried it now and it looks like it still works. In fact it looks like the web-based version still works too. And I am not paying $40/month for it.

Comment: I've seen that. But that's far away the ease of the web interface. That format is a pain for the whole opensource World

Answer (score 1):

Go to "File" menu in Photoshop (trial or free, no matter)

Now go to "Export" submenu and select "Export layers to files".

In the opened dialog, choose PNG as file type and browse for destination folder.

Comment: I'm not seeing this option on Adobe Photoshop CS5.

Comment: At least in the recent versions, it is in the "Export" menu (edited the answer)

Comment: Question: «without using Photoshop», answer : «in Photoshop» : did you read question ?